ROS in Multi-robot exploration
I’m starting my PhD research, which focuses on multi-robot exploration of unknown environments. I am about to start developing my system using ROS and am uncertain whether to go with ROS 1 or ROS 2.
Given that my work involves:
Multi-robot systems (coordination and communication)
Possibly real-time performance requirements
Long-term use (over the next few years)
Which version of ROS would you recommend for someone just starting in 2024? Here are a few points I’m considering:
ROS 1 has a large, well-documented ecosystem with many tools that might be easier for a beginner.
ROS 2 seems to offer better support for multi-robot systems and real-time applications, but I’m concerned about library support and documentation.
I’d love to hear your thoughts, especially from those working with multi-robot systems and those who have made the transition from ROS 1 to ROS 2. Any advice on which version would be best suited for a long-term academic project would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for your guidance.

This question seems to be best suited for a longer, more nuanced discussion. As such, it would benefit from being posted on the ROS Discourse.
A quick answer to your question would be to use ROS 2. ROS 2 has extensive support for multi-robotic applications, and you'd also benefit from (maybe even help improve) OpenRMF. Another strong reason for choosing ROS 2 would be that ROS 1 goes EOL around mid-2025 IIRC.

ROS 2 seems to offer better support for multi-robot systems and real-time applications, but I’m concerned about library support and documentation

You raise a valid concern. However, many libraries that were heavily used with ROS 1 have been ported to ROS 2. For the rest, you can still continue using the ros_bridge, or you can help port a certain library to ROS 2.

Thanks for your feedback, what about available packages in ROS2  ?
